# How to load VideoCapture object from open temporary file

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I would like to take an already open temporary file, load it into a VideoCapture object, and generate a screen capture of the first frame.

From what I can tell in the documentation, you can only create a VideoCapture object one of two ways:

```
#Load from filename
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('filename.avi')

#Load for webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

When I attempt to just load my temp file in, either directly or with the temp name, I get the following error messages:

```
#Hopeful but not valid:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
> AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__trunc__'

#Also no dice
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file.name)
> OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "/var/folders/53/xxdyqg893pbg73pfd7_q_pg00000gp/T/tmpD0Cd6D"
```

How can I load a VideoCapture object with a file object, string buffer, or something similar?

Comment: The OpenCV `cv2.VideoCapture()` API expects a video in format `.mp4`, `.avi`. So the normal workflow implies de-compression of video file depending upon the extension and then decoding the frames. You may not pass a temp file path missing the extension and the required compression directly to OpenCV

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by storing the file in a local temp file.

Assuming you have content, which is django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile -- or something similar -- you can do the following:

```
    import tempfile
    import cv2

    temp_filename = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), content.name)
    local_temp_file = open(temp_filename, "w+")
    content.seek(0)
    local_temp_file.write(content.read())
    local_temp_file.close()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(local_temp_file.name)
```